# C# selenium innerHtml, search for ID

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a little trouble with searching the innerHTML element.
EDIT: (Im sry i mean searching the element from the innerHTML.)

Target: Find Id of the variable inner

sry for my bad english, i hope all understand.

```
//All css elements
var itemHolder = WebDriver.FindElementsByClassName("itemHolder");
//Get singleElement from itemHolder
foreach (var element in itemHolder)
{
    //i think that easy to understand
    if (!element.GetAttribute("style").Equals("display: none;"))
    {
        var innerHtml = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
        //simply regex for find the right one element
        string reg = @"(item app730 context2)";
        bool command = Regex.IsMatch(innerHtml, reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (command)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(element.GetAttribute("innerHTML"));
            var inner = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
            //inner = <div style='border - color: rgb(210, 210, 210); z - index: 3; position: relative; ' class='item app730 context2' id='item730_2_3294048593'></div>

           //now i need id from inner, how can i do it?
           //first variant: Regex inner, found item730_2_3294048593, that is a hard way i find. im bad in regex
           //Regex Example: strike = Regex.Match(inner, "(id=')[a-zA-Z_0-9]{20}").ToString();

           //second and i think bether variant but do not have a plan how to start: P
           // 1. convert inner to html elements
           // 2. search id
           //var found = Regex.Match(inner, "");

            break;
        }

    }
}
```

I hope any can help my, thanks a lot!
Greetings Ivorysmoker

Comment: Regex Out: id='item730_2_3294048593

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a HTML layout like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

If this is the case, you could use an `IWebElement`'s `FindElement` method to look for child elements:

```
IWebElement outer = FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='outer']"));
IWebElement inner = outer.FindElement(By.XPath("./div"));
```

Note that the XPath for inner has a period at the beginning to denote that any results must be a child of the element we are searching from.

From there you can just do `inner.GetAttribute("id")` to get your id.

Comment: Thanks for your fast Answer. Can u tell me the Lib from Xpath? I need to read that. I have startet with regex :P var inner = element.GetAttribute("innerHTML");
  Regex.Match(inner, "(id=')[a-zA-Z_0-9]{20}").ToString(); maybe u can make bether?

Comment: Here's a [short guide on how XPaths work](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp). I would advise you to steer away from using regex to search for child elements as you lose all functionality that selenium provides for interacting with that child element.

Comment: This is not so tragic, I really need only worth the ID. Then another function will take over the rest ;)

Comment: Sry: For Example:  new Actions(WebDriver).DoubleClick(WebDriver.FindElementById(innerId)).Perform();

Comment: Ah I see! Still though, getting the ID through selenium will never change as long as that attribute exists in the DOM. Your regex check could easily fail later down the line though :/

Comment: >Still though, getting the ID through selenium will never change as long as that attribute exists in the DOM. (Yeah i now, that is good for my) :D Sry i cant this explain in english...

Comment: i try hard to understand :D, yeah a little bit. I Think a good way is with regex, if the reg good it cant fail. You know how I possibly with regex say can search everything up ('). Width that i can ignore {20} parameter. See Post Example. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sry i think i make a misstake, EDIT: (Im sry i mean searching the element from the innerHTML.)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ben Chand's answer.  Excuse this pseudo-code:

```
IWebElement outer = By.XPath("//*[@class='itemHolder']");
....
public By getInnerByIndex(int index) {
    By inner = By.XPath(".//div[@id='innerHtml'][" + index + "]");
    By innerLocator = new ByChained(outer, inner);
    return innerLocator;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the expound

Comment: I've expounded your expound to use the correct variable type for `inner`.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, i think this didnt work for my plan. Its all very dynamic. Thanks anyway for your pseudo-code :)

Answer (score 0):

My Way to get ID from innerHTML. (Dynamic Content)

```
 var strike = Regex.Match(inner, "(id=')[a-zA-Z_0-9]{20}");
                    result = strike.ToString().Replace("id='", "");
```

Regex Out: id='item730_2_3294048593
Regex Out Replaced: item730_2_3294048593

Thanks for all answers!

Greetings Ivorysmoker